# VB.Net Regex xml whitebox ssrs pdf

Tags: html, regex, vb.net, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS (2008 r2) report which outputs to a PDF. The report takes a string (which is originally in HTML format) and uses a custom VB function to remove HTML, whitespace and XML characters using regular expressions. The issue is I still get a whitebox character left in the resulting string. It looks like the following symbol:

> □

The VB function I have is as follows:

```
Public Shared Function GetNotes(ByVal strNotes As String) As SqlString
    ' Gets notes within HTML tags
    Dim s As String

    Try
        s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strNotes, "<.*?\n?.*?>", " ")
        s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, " +", " ")
        s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "<[^<>]*?>", " ")
        s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "[\t\r\n] ", "")
        s = s.Replace("&amp;", "&")
        s = s.Replace("&nbsp;", "")
        s = s.Trim()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return New SqlString("Description:  ")
    End Try
    Return New SqlString(s)
End Function
```

What should I add to remove this whitebox?

Comment: Try adding `\uDBC0\uDC00\uDBC0\uDC00\u25A1` to your regex: `s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, "[\t\r\n] |\uDBC0\uDC00\uDBC0\uDC00\u25A1", "")`.

Comment: It didn't work. :/ Since, the whitebox always appeared in the end of the string, I just removed the last character in the function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, the character appears only at the end of the string.

You may easily use `TrimEnd` for this purpose:

```
Dim s As String = "Some text with □"
s = s.TrimEnd("□")
```

Or perhaps, this will also work (since the box is `\u25A1` character):

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "[\u25A1]", String.Empty)
```

Output:

[image]